# SailsJS association

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to get a association with two models:

User -> Module

My User model:

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'user',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 45
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 45
    },
    firstname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 45
    },
    lastname: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 45
    },
    grades: {
      type: 'json',
      defaultsTo:[]
    },
    ....
```

Module model:

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'module',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required:true
    },

    spec_id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      enum: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    },

  }
};
```

The user collection looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58763b49458a93f4785fff0e"
    },
    "grades": [
        {
            "grade": 7.5,
            "mod_id": "587686a4f36d284ed588d72c",
            "try": 1
        },
        {
            "grade": 6.4,
            "mod_id": "587686a4f36d284ed588d72c",
            "try": 2
        }
    ],
    "role_id": "58766274734d1d50c512f493",
    "class_id": "58768634f36d284ed588d6e6",
    "spec_id": "587686a4f36d284ed588d72c",
    "username": "-",
    "password": "-",
    "firstname": "-",
    "lastname": "-",
    "email": "test@test.nl",
    "birthdate": "1995-05-1995",
    "_csrf": "null"
}
```

The query I used to log the above result:

```
var findOneUser = User.find();
findOneUser.where({id: req.session.userID});
findOneUser.populateAll()
findOneUser.exec(function callBack(err,user){
      var singleUser = user.pop().toJSON();
      console.log(singleUser);
 });
```

How could I achieve the following in my models (using user.grades.mod_id as join key), so having a *module* object inside each of my *grades* objects (I am using MongoDB)

```
    {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "58763b49458a93f4785fff0e"
  },
  "grades": [
    {
      "grade": 7.5,
      "module": {
        "name": "bla",
        "description": "-",
        "spec_id": 1
      },
      "try": 1
    },
    {
      "grade": 6.4,
      "module": {
        "name": "bla",
        "description": "-",
        "spec_id": 1
      },
      "try": 2
    }
  ],
  "role_id": "58766274734d1d50c512f493",
  "class_id": "58768634f36d284ed588d6e6",
  "spec_id": "587686a4f36d284ed588d72c",
  "username": "-",
  "password": "-",
  "firstname": "-",
  "lastname": "-",
  "email": "test@test.nl",
  "birthdate": "-",
  "_csrf": "null"
}
```

I saw alot on nested associations; but I think this is a bit different, also found this.. [sails.js nested models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020055/sails-js-nested-models) It's kind of similar, but comparing to this example I'd want to join with a value inside of the *'profile'* JSON object.

Comment: I think what you want to do is not supported. You can either create a separate Model for `Grade` or in current schema, collect all module ids from  user result and fetch modules separately and join them together.

Comment: Can I create a Grades model even if it is actually inside my User model? Wouldnt that cause problems?

Comment: No, it can't be inside. A separate `Grade` model in `Grade.js` and it will be stored separately in Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this:

Create a separate Grade model. It will be stored separately in MongoDB (not using Mongo in preferred way)

OR Write code to populate modules after getting user

```
User.findOne(1).exec(function(err, user) {
  user = user.toJSON();
  var moduleIds = _.map(user.grades, 'mod_id');

  Module.find(moduleIds).exec(function(err, modules) {
    _.forEach(user.grades, function(grade) {
      var module = _.find(modules, { 'id': grade.mod_id });
      grade.module = module;
    });
    console.log('User', user);
    return;
  });
});
```

Comment: Good to know. Be aware, this works well when dealing with single user. If/when you are showing list of user, you might want to fetch all `Modules` (assuming they are in hundreds/thousands) then join in similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to understand where you have issue as it is straight forward after looking into docs.

in User.js model:

```
mod_id: {
model: 'module' // or modules depends how you have it declared
}
```

in Module.js model:

```
users: {
collection: 'user',
via: 'mod+id'
}
```

Comment: If I do this my user model still doesn't return the module object inside the grade objects, I edited my question with the query I used to log the user result

Comment: I also only have 'grades' defined as an JSON object in my 'User' model, I don't actually have the value inside grades 'mod_id' defined, if that makes sense.

Comment: because you have nested relations. You have to apply association user->grade and then grade->module and use populate.

Comment: @M U but my user collection already has the 'grades' (grades doesnt have its own model) array in its collection.